# Is there standard curry() function in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, currying

I want to apply a function partially. Is there standard concise way to do any kind of currying in Elixir?

I know I can do somethings like this:

```elixir
new_func = fn(arg2, arg3) -> my_func(constant, arg2, arg3) end

new_func2 = fn -> my_func2(constant) end
```

but it looks ugly.

Comment: Have you seen this blog post? http://blog.patrikstorm.com/function-currying-in-elixir

Comment: Thanks. As we can see, I actually was looking for something more simple, i.e. for closures. What about currying, the article is 1,5 years old, so I was not sure that it is still actual.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the capture `&` operator to clean it up a bit:

```
plus2 = &Kernel.+(2, &1)
plus2.(4)
6
```

Notice the dot `.` in between plus2 and it's parens

Since this is kind of syntactic sugar for

```
plus2 = fn(right) -> Kernel.+(2, right) end
```

all the same rules apply. Like you must supply all arguments to the function you're "currying" and you can place the positional arguments in any order.

[Docs on the `&` operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1)

Comment: Thanks! This looks better, but it does not work with func/1 for some reason. This code "create_named_window = &create_window(title)" produces CompileError: "invalid args for &, expected an expression in the format of &Mod.fun/arity, &local/arity or a capture containing at least one argument as &1, got: create_window(title)"

Comment: @raacer when you use the capture operator you have to have at least one argument, so you could `&create_window(&1)` but not like you have above.

Comment: Also what you're describing in your comment isn't quite a curried function, it's a closure. Rather than creating a partial function application, you've satisfied all the arguments and are trying to call it with `title` in scope. What you want is `fn -> create_window(title) end` as it's specifically for creating closures. Even in a language famous for currying like Haskell the currying you're describing above unfortunately doesn't exist.

Comment: I got it. I need closures, and currying for function with one argument is nonsense :) Thanks a lot for explanation. Ok, so what about currying? Is there a built-in method to write something like `get_plus_n = curry(+)` and then `plus2 = get_plus_n(2)`? Does some syntactic sugar allow to write somethings like `get_plus_n = &(&(&&1+&1))`?

Comment: @raacer no there's no built in or standard way to do that, Elixir doesn't have partial function application. You would have to write a function or use a library that wraps functions and essentially does what we're doing above.

Comment: Why is not it in standard library? I thought this feature is something that should be in any functional language.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way.

```elixir
multiply = fn fac -> fn num -> fac*num end end

multiply.(2).(8)

double = multiply.(2)
double.(6)
```

You could also do the below. Although it seems like only the last function can use the capture syntax, as using nested captures throws and syntax error.

```elixir
multiply = fn fac -> &(fac*&1) end
```